# Why does Haskell's `transpose` function in Data.List not use `head` and `tail`?

Tags: list, haskell, transpose, nested-lists, definition

I've just spent some time working on a problem for which I needed to translate a list of lists a certain way. After successfully working through it I came up with this solution:

```hs
translate :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
translate ([]:xss) = []
translate xss      = (map head xss) : (translate $ map tail xss)
```

Very shortly afterwards, i realized that I was simply trying to **transpose a matrix**... I thought "I probably lost a lot of time trying to do this, as surely Haskell has a function in its standard libraries to do such a common operation." So I decided to check, and unsurprisingly I found that the `Data.List` module includes a `transpose` function.

But what was actually surprising to me was the way it was defined:

```
transpose               :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose []             = []
transpose ([]   : xss)   = transpose xss
transpose ((x:xs) : xss) = (x : [h | (h:_) <- xss]) : transpose (xs : [ t | (_:t) <- xss])
```

It uses list comprehensions instead of `head` and `tail`, which I thought was interesting but could not figure out why it did so.

**Is there a reason why it is better to use list comprehension instead of the pre-defined `head` and `tail` functions (with `map`)**, the way that I did with my function? Is it something to do with the efficiency of the code?

I am not necessarily new to Haskell, but I am not an expert either. That being said, *more technical answers and explanations* would also be greatly appreciated as I am hoping to learn more about the intricacies of the language going forward (and even if I don't understand the reason now I will know what I have to research).

Comment: Because for empty lists that would error.

Comment: You typo'd the first code sample (`translate` vs `transpose'`. If you tried it on a variety of inputs (ie. non-equal lengths of inner lists) you'd discover it crashes as `head`, `tail` are partial, which is why the library version uses list comprehension to implicitly drop (non-initial) empty lists.

Comment: Note that `head` and `tail` are themselves defined in terms of pattern matching (just like everything else) so by using pattern matching directly you skip some indirection and get right at the heart of the matter. Generally speaking, you should prefer pattern matching and reserve `head` and `tail` for specific uses -- not the other way around.

Comment: two other ways to define it that also work with jagged lists, and with `take 1 . map (take 1) $ .... ((1:undefined):undefined)`, are: `trs1 [] = [] ; trs1 xs = concatMap (take 1) xs : trs1 [t | (_:t) <- xs]` and even `trs2 xs = case concatMap (take 1) xs of [] -> [] ; a -> a : trs2 (map (drop 1) xs)`.

Comment: the last one (`trs2`) indeed a bit less efficient than the first, since it doesn't weed out the empty lists early  (as the first one does, as indeed does the library version).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *empty* lists, functions like `head` and `tail` will error. Note that if you write:

```
[h | (h:_) <- xss]
```

then this is *not* equivalent to `map head xss`. Indeed, the above list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
let ok (h:_) = pure h
    ok _ = fail "…"
in xss >>= ok
```

So in case the pattern matching fails, then we return a `fail ""` value. For a list this is the empty list:

```
Prelude> fail "" :: [Int]
[]
```

This is important for non-rectangular lists that we want to transpose, for example:

```
Prelude Data.List> transpose [[1,4,2,5],[1,3], [1,9,5,8]]
[[1,1,1],[4,3,9],[2,5],[5,8]]
```

So it will transform:

```
[ 1 4 2 5]
[ 1 3 ]
[ 1 9 5 8]
```

to:

```
[1 1 1]
[4 3 9]
[2 5]
[5 8]
```

Whereas if one uses `head` and `tail` eventually when it aims to calculate the `head` and `tail` in the third row, it will crash on the `[1,3]` list:

```
Prelude Data.List> transpose' [[1,4,2,5],[1,3], [1,9,5,8]]
[[1,1,1],[4,3,9],[2,*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very detailed and I understood perfectly! I guess if I test my code more extensively next time I will end up finding the answer out on my own... :)